# How to "protect" Sheets and leave some columns unlocked?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a button and code to LOCK (or protect) the sheets in my workbook. I also created a button and code to UNLOCK (or unprotect) the sheets in my workbook.

I have columns I want the user to be able to enter info; but I do not want the whole sheet unlocked/unprotected.

Example on my Training sheet, cells K6:U3175 I'd like unprotected. Here's what I've tried:

```vb
'This is for the Lock Button on the WOOKBOOK TIPS sheet.
'Upon clicking once on the LOCK button, the scripts below re-protecting all the worksheets.

   ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="password"
   Sheets("1  - TRAINING").Protect "password"
   ActiveSheet.Range("1  - TRAINING").Range("K6:U3175").Locked = False
```

I get the error in the code to unlock the range. How can I unprotect just that range of cells?

Comment: You need to unlock the range *before* you protect the sheet.  You can't unlock cells on a locked sheet.

Answer (score 1):

In the following order:

1. un-protect the worksheet
2. change the lock/unlocked setting on any cells or groups of cells
3. re-protect the worksheet

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to follow the order of events provided by Gary's answer.  In code, this'll look like

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheet(1)
    .Unprotect "1234" 'insert your pasword here (1)
    .Range("A:B").Cells.Locked = False '(2)
    .Protect "1234" 'insert your pasword here (3)
End With
```